# PDO throws an Notice: Undefined index when using fetchAll in a WHILE loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, undefined-index

I'm new in the PHP world and I need a bit of help here.
I'm trying to extract a data from database, I'm using PDO to do it.
I have the following PHP code without success, throwing back error notice:

```
$pairingsistem='1'; 
$pecahan='1';

if($pairingsistem == "1"){

$skrg=time();
$tablaz = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tb_gh where saldo > 0 and status='pending' order by id ASC limit 0,1");
while ($registroz = $tablaz ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
//use $results   
$kurirz=$registroz["username"]; //line 47 starts here
$biayaz=$registroz["saldo"];
$idnyaz=$registroz["id"];
$bankeem=$registroz["bank"];
$norekeem=$registroz["norek"];
$bitcoineem=$registroz["bitcoin"];
$pmeem=$registroz["perfectmoney"];
$fasapayeem=$registroz["fasapay"];
$namaeem=$registroz["nama"];
$phoneeem=$registroz["phone"];
$emaileem=$registroz["email"];
$paketzeem=$biayaz*$pecahan;
$surabaya=$paketzeem/$pecahan;
//shortline
```

> Notice: Undefined index: username in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 47
>
> Notice: Undefined index: saldo in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 48
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 49
>
> Notice: Undefined index: bank in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Undefined index: norek in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 51
>
> Notice: Undefined index: bitcoin in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 52
>
> Notice: Undefined index: perfectmoney in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 53
>
> Notice: Undefined index: fasapay in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 54
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nama in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 55
>
> Notice: Undefined index: phone in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 56
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in
>   /home/u427750052/public_html/automatch.inc.php on line 57

this has been the warnings. Though I have troubleshot all I could within the scope of my knowledge on this so far.

Comment: Thanks chris. i think it worked. So if i am using fetchall, i just while '$registroz = $tablaz ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);'

Comment: *"Don't loop with fetchAll, loop with fetch, or fetchall"* - @chris85 You said not to use `fetchAll` but said "or fetchall"`, typo? It's a bit confusing lol

Comment: Thanks to you'all. i think the problem has been resolved. :-)

Comment: @chris85 I suggest you place an (detailed) answer for this, since the undefined index usually used to dupe questions of this nature with the errors shows, doesn't cover this. There is a db-related answer that was added recently but it doesn't cover this particular issue.

Comment: if Chris posts an answer, consider accepting it in order to mark the question as solved and welcome to Stack Overflow. Edit: and he has.

Comment: @chris85 You're welcome. Looks good to me.

Comment: To anyone wanting to mark this question as a duplicate of the usually-used `undefined index` Q&A, this is not a duplicate of it, it's a particular case.

Comment: @LegiSmith Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` and `fetchAll` are throwing you off here. You either need to loop a `fetch` or `fetchall` then iterate over the returned result.

So either:

```
while ($registroz = $tablaz ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

or

```
$registroz = $tablaz ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($registroz as $row) {
```

but since you have it returning only 1 row you don't need a loop or `fetchall`.

```
$registroz = $tablaz ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It's pretty interesting to see the undefined index notices show when using PDO like that. I hardly use PDO myself (oh I stand at getting criticized by someone here hahaha!!). This is a first for me.

Comment: Thanks. this was really the best way to explain in my terms. :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$registroz` with the fetchall is a multidimensional array, the names are at the second level. I think `$kurirz=$registroz[0]["username"];` would have worked also.

Comment: @chris85 Yep. Btw, can you upvote [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406109/having-trouble-with-pdo-notice-undefined-index#comment77772907_45406109) please?